# Gridview auto load data when scroll bar reach the bottom

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, gridview, devexpress, scrollbar

Hello guys I have a sample gridview [image]

Here's what i want to happen.

When I open the form i load top 100 of data from the server in to the gridview. When I scroll down and reach the end of the scroll bar I want to load another data from 101 - 200. 
so the data in the gridview is 1 to 200.
How do I determine if the scroll bar reach the end?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on the version of XtraGrid you are using - perhaps you should check out [InstantFeedback](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WinForms/Grid/instant-feedback.xml)

It's a datasource that dynamicly get rows, when they come into view.

The great thing about this is - that it's a standard DevExpress component - so you don't have to invent anything youself.

OR:

You could force that behavior with some thing like this:

```
    private bool _working = false;
    private void view_RowStyle(object sender, RowStyleEventArgs e)
    {
      if(_working) return;

      var view = sender as GridView;
      if (view != null)
      {
        int lastRowIndex = (view.GridControl.DataSource as BindingSource).Count;
        if (view.IsRowVisible(lastRowIndex) == RowVisibleState.Visible)
        {
          _working = true;
          //go get more rows.
          _working = false;
        }
      }
    }
```

This assumes that you are using a `BindingSource` (if not, the you must change the cast type).

I handle the `RowStyle` event because the code in this event are executed "all time time".

Comment: I am using v10.1. I load all my data into the datasource but I don't want to load everything.I just want to know how to determine if the scroll reach the bottom. I want my gridView to function like facebook once you scroll down it loads old status. Thanks :)

Comment: ok - the InstantFeedback is not avalible until v. 11.x. I'v updated my answer

Comment: Thanks for the Help.I think its lastRowIndex-1. the problem is it won't trigger if i use the scroll bar.

Comment: Sorry.I just Discoverd it will just Trigger when I use the Scroll bar and click on the grid. Is there a way not to trigger this all the time?

Comment: @Snippet hmmm obvious you could just add a condition wrapping all the code, but i'm not sure what that condition sould be. hmmm maybe you need something like a flag to mark that you are doing work. See edit answer

Comment: Yup I added something like that. Maybe there's no way around. I'm worried this may take some performance on the program because even i am not scrolling or touching the grid, the event still triggers.

Comment: @Snippet I see you point. but I don't think it will be a problem. 1) the code we added to the event is mostly just *looking* at varaibles.
2) the code that activates the event runs regardless of the subscribers - so we are not *creating* a `while(true)` loop, we are just placing som code in one.

Answer (score 2):

You cah handle the scrolling to end (and any another conditions) via handling the `Scroll` event of GridControl's embedded scrollbar.
Here is the approach details:

```
var sb = GetScrollBar(gridControl1, ScrollBarType.Vertical);
sb.Scroll += new ScrollEventHandler(sb_Scroll);
//...
void sb_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e) {
    var scrollBar = sender as DevExpress.XtraEditors.ScrollBarBase;
    if(e.NewValue == (scrollBar.Maximum - scrollBar.LargeChange)) {
        MessageBox.Show("Last row is reached!");
    }
}
ScrollBarBase GetScrollBar(GridControl gridControl, ScrollBarType type) {
    foreach(Control c in gridControl.Controls) {
        var scrollBar = c as ScrollBarBase;
        if(scrollBar != null && scrollBar.ScrollBarType == type)
            return scrollBar;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @DmitryG. The code runs perfect but if i use the mouseWheel it won't trigger.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the displayed rows count and calculate based on the total loaded rows and check in the TopRowChanged event and see if you need to load any more rows.
This is a more manually approach for this situation.

Also you can use the grid in server mode which does this for you.

Regards,
Mishu